# Android + Facebook sdk + facebook.isSessionValid() not working correctly?

Tags: android, facebook

Installed the official FB app for the emulator, and logged in. Generated a working App ID for my application, yet when I trace:

```
facebook.isSessionValid()
```

I receive "false"... is this a bug?  Any help is appreciated!

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("***********");
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;
        .....
    public void add_to_facebook(View view) {
        //add to facebook
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);
        if(access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }
        if(expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {

            facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                    Log.d("fb", "onComplete()");
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                    editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                    editor.commit();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    Log.d("fb", "onFacebookError");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Log.d("fb", "onError()");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.d("fb", "onCancel");
                }
            });
        }
        //feed dialog
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new SampleDialogListener());      
    }

    public class SampleDialogListener extends BaseDialogListener {

        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "Dialog Success! post_id=" + postId);
            } else {
                Log.d("Facebook-Example", "No wall post made");
            }
        }
    }

        ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was setting the dialog too early in the process.  This remedied the situation:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("fb", ""+resultCode);
        if(facebook.isSessionValid()){
            facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new SampleDialogListener());
        }
    }
```